# General term for a remote control?

Tags: vocabulaire

What is the common French term for a remote control, such as is used to manipulate a television, stereo system, game console, remote control car (toy), or a ceiling fan?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general term would be *télécommande* though there exists a myriad of other words for each system, often region-based, although they can overlap.

I've never heard of a game console remote control. I usually hear game controller, and in that case, it is *manette de jeu*.

Comment: Regarding the "region-based" bit, in Quebec, a common informal word for any type of remote control is *manette*.

Answer (score 1):

Usage courant en informatique :

Dans les salles informatiques (réseaux ou serveurs) j'ai souvent entendu : 
"prendre la main" sur une machine distante, ou "as-tu la main" sur telle machine (qui se trouve souvent dans un autre ville, mais parfois au sous-sol)

Dans les procédures j'ai souvent lu :
prévoir/obtenir/réaliser un contrôle à distance.

et aussi le mot télécontrôle lorsque l'on analyse les images satellitaires.

*Post Scriptum*
J'avais déjà entendu le mot franglais *[zapette](http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=11252)* (contraction de to *zap* + manette ?) lorsqu'il s'agit d'une télécommande, mais "lâches les manettes et viens manger" pour demander à un enfant d'arrêter de jour avec sa console de jeu et de venir à table.

*Digression*
Pour lutter contre le franglais il faut le déstructurer et se servir de ses armes, en inventant des mots qui n'existent pas (merci Jean Yanne) :

Imaginer l'interjection interrogative proférée d'une voix traînante par un garçon (c'est paraît-il une manie majoritairement masculine de tripoter les télécommandes) "arrêtes de *zapir*", ou, "ton *zappoir*, tu sais ou tu ..."

Comment: "a remote control" c'est une télécommande, un objet, pas l'action de prendre la main à distance sur quelquechose.

Comment: @Mat : J'ai toujours entendu ce genre de définition "Permet à l'administrateur réseau de visionner et de contrôler à distance les ordinateurs du réseau sans avoir à quitter son poste de travail. L'administrateur se connecte sur l'ordinateur situé à distance par le réseau et, voit le bureau de l'ordinateur situé à distance sur son propre écran, il lance des programmes, modifie les paramètres de l'ordinateur, etc. en utilisant son propre clavier et sa souris". Cf.:  (http://www.01net.com/telecharger/windows/Utilitaire/reseau/fiches/26288.html), mais je vis dans l'hexagone loin des anglophones

Comment: "remote control" tout court, utilisé comme un verbe, c'est bien ca. Mais "**a** remote control" c'est un objet. "I can take remote control over my TV with a remote control." => je peux commander ma télé à distance avec une télécommande.

Comment: @Mat Merci de cette précision, je n'avais pas perçu la nuance.